# How to Display total number of review in bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am tring to display total number of review but following code is not working

```
<span style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideReviewLink%%">
<a href="#ProductReviews" onclick="%%GLOBAL_ReviewLinkOnClick%%">
%%GLOBAL_ReviewLinkText%%
</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Nothing in that code relates to showing the number of reviews though dear. Are the reviews appearing at all? If so, you can use JS to count the number of elements, and that will be the number. If you link to your site I can write the JS for you.

Comment: @RootBearFloat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209198/how-to-count-review-per-product-and-show-in-product-listing-in-big-commerce?noredirect=1#comment69617582_41209198

Comment: Try `%%GLOBAL_ProductNumReviews%%`. It should work in the scope of `ProductDetails` panel.